# Nginx running ip access in browser work but dns timeout

Tags: nginx, dns, debian, hosts, debian-buster

I'm running into an issue that I can't solve myself...
I'm running a Debian 10 server with nginx freshly installed on it.

IPV4: `149.56.45.129`, DNS: `yocha.app`

Result of `hostnamectl`:

```
Static hostname: yocha.app
Icon name: computer-vm
Chassis: vm
Machine ID: d72735cff36a41f0a5326f0bb7eb1778
Boot ID: 72dd9022a4894eeea82bc74480543823
Virtualization: kvm
Operating System: Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Kernel: Linux 4.19.0-13-cloud-amd64
Architecture: x86-64
```

My `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
149.56.45.129   yocha.app

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost       ip6-localhost   ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

My nginx `sites-avaible/default`:

```
 server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name yocha.app;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}
```

When I access my ip address in the browser, I do get the nginx welcome message which is good I guess.

BUT when I try to access the dns the request timed out with no return...
I can log with ssh on my dns, I can ping it with no problems I even can curl it but when It comes to access it on a Browser, nothing happens.

```
curl -I http://149.56.45.129:80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 13:40:16 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 13:05:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "60097c10-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

me@yocha:~$ curl -I http://yocha.app:80
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.14.2
Date: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 13:40:25 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 612
Last-Modified: Thu, 21 Jan 2021 13:05:20 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "60097c10-264"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

[http://yocha.app on a browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKm28.png)

Anyone having a clue for me ?
Thanks a lot in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Your site is redirecting to https:

```
$ curl -v http://yocha.app
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.14.2
< Date: Fri, 29 Jan 2021 20:21:46 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 185
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://yocha.app/
```

and port 443 is not open or it's blocked:

```
$ telnet yocha.app 443
Trying 149.56.45.129...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

DNS is fine: check your firewall or make sure nginx is propertly configured to listen on port 443 and to serve an ssl certificate.